# RabbitMQ SpringAMQP xml configuration

Tags: xml, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, pika

I am trying to have a small application making use of RabbitMQ, wherein my sender is written in Spring AMQP xml configuration and the receiver is written in python using PIKA.
 Please let me know if my approach is correct.

Here is my sender file-

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringAMQPRabbitSender {
    private final static String SENDER_XML = "springamqp-rabbit-sender-context.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate = (AmqpTemplate)(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SENDER_XML)).getBean("amqpTemplate");
      int messagCount = 0;
      while (messagCount < 10){
        amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("tp.routingkey.1", "Message # " + messagCount++);
      }
      System.out.println( messagCount + " message(s) sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Here is my springamqp-rabbit-sender-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" 
host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
exchange="tpExchange"/> 
</beans>
```

Now this is my python receiver-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParamet(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='tpExchange',
                     exchange_type='topic')

channel.queue_declare(queue = "tpQueue")

key = "tp.routingkey.1"
channel.queue_bind(exchange='tpExchange',
                   queue="tpQueue",
                   routing_key="tp.routingkey.1")

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (key, body))

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                  queue="tpQueue",
                  no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Is this  correct?? Am I missing out anything? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct. That's all? Do you face some issue? Is there some errors when you send message? In general: what made you to come to us for the help?

Comment: I just wanted to know if in xml file, is it necessary to configure queue-exchange binding? I had a doubt, so wanted to clarify. As I studied, the above configuration in xml at sender side should suffice. But since in few examples I saw the queue exchange binding configured at sender side also..So  I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But since in few examples I saw the queue exchange binding configured at sender side also..So I wanted to clarify.

No, you definitely don't need to do that on the sender side. There is just need to know an `exchange` and `routing key`. The queue and its binding even not a problem of the receiver, but we usually do binding there.

The normal way to go, of course, is a Broker side configuration.